# Having trouble calculating the correct Gaussian Kernel values from the Gaussian function formula

Tags: image-processing, kernel, canny-edge-detector, gaussian-kernel, image-smoothing

I'm having trouble calculating the same values for a Gaussian filter kernel as those derived in the [Canny edge detector Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector#Gaussian_filter)

It states:

> The equation for a Gaussian filter kernel of size (2k+1)x(2k+1) is
> given by:
>
> $$ H_{i,j} =  \frac {1} {2\pi\sigma^2} \exp\left(- \frac {(i - (k +
> 1))^2 + (j - (k + 1)^2} {2\sigma^2}\right) \\
> ; 1 \le i, j \le (2k + 1)
> $$
>
> Here is an example of a 5×5 Gaussian filter, used to create the adjacent image, with $\sigma = 1$. (The asterisk denotes a convolution operation.)
>
> $$ \textbf{B} = \frac{1}{159}
> \begin{bmatrix} 
> 2 & 4 & 5 & 4 & 2 \\ 
> 4 & 9 & 12 & 9 & 4 \\ 
> 5 & 12 & 15 & 12 & 5 \\ 
> 4 & 9 & 12 & 9 & 4 \\ 
> 2 & 4 & 5 & 4 & 2 \\ 
> \end{bmatrix}
> * \textbf{A} $$

My work for just the first term:

For a 5x5 filter, I calculate k using the equation $2k+1 = 5$:
$$ k = \frac{5 - 1}{2} \rightarrow k = 2 $$

The range for $i, j$ now becomes $1 \le i, j \le 5$

For $i, j = (1, 1)$ & $\sigma = 1$:

$$
\begin{align*}
H_{1,1} &= \frac {1} {2\pi\cdot1^2} \exp\left(- \frac {(1 - (2 +
1))^2 + (1 - (2 + 1)^2} {2\cdot1^2}\right)\\
&= \frac {1} {2\pi} \exp\left(- \frac {(-2)^2 + (-2)^2} {2}\right)\\
&= \frac {1} {2\pi} \exp\left(-4\right)\\
&= (0.1592...) \cdot (0.0183...)\\
&\approx 0.0029\\
\end{align*}
$$

Looking at the result from the Wiki page for the top left-most term, it's equal to $\frac{1}{159}\cdot2 \approx 0.0126$

Applying my method to calculate the entire kernel I get:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
0.0029 & 0.0131 & 0.0215 & 0.0131 & 0.0029 \\ 
0.0131 & 0.0585 & 0.0965 & 0.0585 & 0.0131 \\ 
0.0215 & 0.0965 & 0.1592 & 0.0965 & 0.0215 \\ 
0.0131 & 0.0585 & 0.0965 & 0.0585 & 0.0131 \\ 
0.0029 & 0.0131 & 0.0215 & 0.0131 & 0.0029 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The kernel on the Wiki page resolves to:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
0.0126 & 0.0252 & 0.0314 & 0.0252 & 0.0126 \\ 
0.0252 & 0.0566 & 0.0755 & 0.0566 & 0.0252 \\ 
0.0314 & 0.0755 & 0.0943 & 0.0755 & 0.0314 \\ 
0.0252 & 0.0566 & 0.0755 & 0.0566 & 0.0252 \\ 
0.0126 & 0.0252 & 0.0314 & 0.0252 & 0.0126 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Both results are rounded to 4 decimal places. Am I doing something wrong in my calculations? Looking at the more general equation:

$$
G(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}e^{-\frac{x^2 + y^2}{2\sigma^2}}
$$
where $x, y$ are the horizontal and vertical distances from the center of the kernel, respectively. In the example above, this is accounted for by the $(i - (k + 1))$ and $(j - (k + 1))$ terms. Yet, all other terms are fixed or constants, so there must be something wrong with my understanding of the $i, j, k$ variables.

Comment: Check these out:

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/69619/how-to-make-a-gaussian-filter/69625?noredirect=1#comment143998_69625

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/54375/how-to-approximate-gaussian-kernel-for-image-blur

Comment: @CedronDawg Thank you! Very informative stuff there. I stumbled on your dsprelated blog post but most of it went over my head, for now :P

So if I understand correctly, I am actually computing the "true" values of the Gaussian kernel. What I am comparing it to (on the wiki page) is just an approximate integer representation?

Comment: "Just"??!!  It's proud to be a quantized normalized sampling of the continuous Gaussian.  Notice that the coefficients should add up to the divisor on the outside.  Thus applying it to a level surface has no effect.  Integer calculations tend to be much faster.  My latest article is about the discrete vs continuous Gaussian, that undoubtedly has a 2D analog, but I haven't gotten there yet.

Comment: Point taken! I don't think I'm quite at the level where I can fully appreciate what's going on with it, but I'll probably be digging deeper into your articles and your code to learn more.

Comment: My articles are mostly about the 1D DFT and parameter estimation.  Image processing is a separate interest area that I haven't really written about yet.  I do have a few in my queue, the first is about gradient estimation on a noisy surface.

Comment: You may find these interesting as well:

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/58341/after-advice-about-detecting-focus-quality-of-objects-in-a-photo-detected-using/58427#58427

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/58226/auto-detection-of-rotation-angle-on-arbitrary-image-with-orthogonal-features/58234#58234